# Web Audio API: How to keep music playing when iphone is off?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, html5-audio, web-audio-api

The context is: iOS 9.3.2 Safari.

I'm making audio visualization on a web page. If i use the `<audio>` tag, play it and turn off the iphone then the audio keeps playing. But [Safari doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20audio%20api) Web Audio API through streaming - `AudioContext.createMediaElementSource()` - so i have to buffer and decode the entire audio file in order to visualize it - `AudioContext.createBufferSource()`.

In this case audio stops playing when i turn off the iphone.

My current solution is to add, besides `createBufferSource`, the `<audio>` tag with a tiny silent mp3 source file that loops all the time. In this case everything works fine - the iphone, when turned off, plays both the silent mp3 & the buffered *real* mp3.

**The question:** Is there a more straightforward solution (meta tags, manifest, etc.)?

---

*btw Android 5.1 Chrome keeps playing the buffered audio as is and desktop Safari supports `createMediaElementSource`*

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: @aareeph Nope :( Though maybe Safari became smarter since then.

Comment: still seems to be the case. I have a similar project https://github.com/martian17/pulseaudio-broadcast-server/blob/main/static/main.js that uses AudioContext.createBufferSource() and websocket to stream audio, but the audio stops playing when I close safari or move to another tab. Here's my useragent
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1